# What's the idiomatic way of creating a Rust Error shim?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have two error types that are defined in external crates.  Let's call them `foo::Error` and `bar::Error`.  Because they are both defined externally, I cannot create a direct `From` or `Into` conversion between the two.

In my own crate, I'm using implementing a trait from `bar`, which expects return values of `Result<T, bar::Error>`.  In the methods of my implementation, I'm calling functions from `foo`, which return many `Result<T, foo::Error>` types.

I would like to map these `foo::Error` errors to `bar::Error` errors, so that my trait implementation is neat, but the best that I can do is create a separate shim error, and then have a clunky `.map_err(ShimErr::from)?` on everything.  This can start to litter up my code if I'm calling many `foo::` functions in my implementation.

```rust
use foo;
use bar;

struct ShimErr(foo::Error);

impl From<foo::Error> for ShimErr {
    fn from(e: foo::Error) -> Self {
        Self(e)
    }
}

impl From<ShimErr> for bar::Error {
    fn from(e: ShimErr) -> Self {
        Self{}
    }
}

struct MyTraitImpl {}

impl bar::SomeTrait for MyTraitImpl {
    fn do_something() -> Result<i32, bar::Error> {
        // FIXME: THIS IS CLUNKY
        let foo_val: i32 = foo::call_something().map_err(ShimErr::from)?;
        Ok(foo_val * 2)
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?  In an ideal world, there would be a way to just use `?`

If I remove `map_err` and try to use `?` directly:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `bar::Error`
  --> shimtest.rs:32:49
   |
32 |         let foo_val: i32 = foo::call_something()?;
   |                                                 ^ the trait `std::convert::From<foo::Error>` is not implemented for `bar::Error`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <bar::Error as std::convert::From<ShimErr>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but I suggest you to read this great article https://blog.yoshuawuyts.com/error-handling-survey . It is not about Error Handling in Rust but about using many different ways/crates to do it. Also, mode detailed content you can find on this link https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/6-error-handling.html

Comment: Doesn't `?` call `into` automatically? What happens if you remove the `map_err`?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios updated my post with the error output.  Rust doesn't know how to convert a `foo::Error` to a `bar::Error` without going through the shim.  `foo::Error::into() -> ShimErr::into() -> bar::Error`

Comment: @AndrewMoffat Oh right, sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score -1):

The way I handle multiple different errors from other crates would be to make my own `Error` enum and use that instead of other errors directly.

So instead of a tuple struct that only contains `foo::Error`, you can create an enum that can have both `foo::Error` and `bar::Error`.  After this, you can convert all the errors to the custom enum error with `?`.

In certain cases, I think you'll still need to use something like `.map_err(Into::into)` occasionally, but usually only when the variable being returned is a `Result` with an external error.

```rust
use bar::Error as BarError;
use foo::Error as FooError;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Result as FmtResult};
use std::result::Result as StdResult;

/// Common result type that uses the custom error
pub type Result<T> = StdResult<T, Error>;

/// Common error type used as a holder for errors from various other libraries.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Bar(BarError),
    Foo(FooError),
}

impl From<BarError> for Error {
    fn from(err: BarError) -> Error {
        Error::Bar(err)
    }
}

impl From<FooError> for Error {
    fn from(err: FooError) -> Error {
        Error::Foo(err)
    }
}

impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> FmtResult {
        match *self {
            Error::Bar(ref inner) => inner.fmt(f),
            Error::Foo(ref inner) => inner.fmt(f),
        }
    }
}

impl StdError for Error {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        match *self {
            Error::Bar(ref inner) => inner.description(),
            Error::Foo(ref inner) => inner.description(),
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the custom `Result` and `Error` as follows.

```rust
// this Result is now our custom Result type with custom error
// same as std::result::Result<i32, Error> (with Error as our custom error)
fn do_something() -> Result<i32> {
    let foo_val: i32 = foo::call_something()?; // should convert to our custom error
    Ok(foo_val * 2)
}

fn do_something_else() -> Result<i32> {
    // directly returning a Result<> with a different error type will need map_err
    foo::call_something().map_err(Into::into)
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to change the signature of `fn do_something() -> Result<i32>` to be the custom error, since it is a trait method from `bar::SomeTrait` though.